# IE11 AJAX request from HTTP to broken cert HTTPS

Tags: ajax, http, https, internet-explorer-11

I'm currently trying to make an AJAX request in a crappy dev environment. My current app is on HTTP and is making an AJAX request to an HTTPS endpoint with a broken certificate. Is there any way I can get my IE11 to stop rejecting the request?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for fixing the messed up SSL cert situation here: https://medium.com/@ali.dev/how-to-trust-any-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-ie11-and-edge-fa7b416cac68